# 'TypeError: null is not an object' with prompt in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a problem with this error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'PromptAndroid.promptWithArgs')
```

I dug a bit on the internet, but couldn't solve the problem.
I did this import as I should:

```
import prompt from 'react-native-prompt-android';
```

here's the code snippet where the problem is :

```
  addProduct() {
    prompt(
      "Enter name",
      "",
      [
        { text: "Cancel", style: "cancel" },
        { text: "OK", onPress: this.addNewProd.bind(this) },
      ],
      {
        type: "plain-text",
        placeholder: "placeholder",
      }
    );
  }
```

I was left with the last functionality in the application - exactly adding a "product" to the list with products - it was supposed to be done as a pop-up window after pressing a button in which the user enters the name, presses 'ok' and that's it.

EDIT#

Out of curiosity, I tried to do it with an ordinary "alert" and it works - it adds a new product with the index, but of course I can't give it a name because it's just an 'alert'

Url to github with the source file:
https://github.com/PrzemekCraker/nutrition-app/blob/dirty-code/src/screens/AddProduct.js

thanks for your time!

Comment: I can't see any problem with the arguments, except that you are binding the function `addNewProd` inside, maybe this is causing the error.. Try binding it before calling prompt and then change the value of onPress to: `onPress: addNewProd`

Comment: @SomoKRoceS I don't know if I understood correctly, cuz I'm still a noob, but I did this:
  `addNewProduct = this.addNewProduct.bind(this)` right after calling prompt 
and keeps getting the same problem - `PromptAndroid.promptWithArgs` - still pointing to bind? 
I added a small edit to the thread - take a look if you want to spend a moment more trying to help.

Comment: try `this.addNewProduct = this.addNewProduct.bind(this)` before `prompt`. Then inside prompt: `....... onPress: this.addNewProd }.........`

Comment: @SomoKRoceS I've already tried this too and
the same error keeps crashing.

I think I have to give up on `prompt`